# Using 'aligned' inside 'aligned' (double level like staircase)

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I know it's probably not recommended, since one can always rewrite it into two or more equations. However, I have a particular example where it would be better to have it as shown in the figure below. The minor mathematical justification is that this highlights the steps of approximations. $\alpha$

[image]

The example shown is done by, from the outermost layer, `align` ---> `aligned` ---> manual (`hspace`, `hphantom`, etc.). I prefer not to use `hphantom` to repeat at each level with increasing length, because this makes the code less readable. The last equation most of the code would be in phantom. I briefly considered using `split', but` align` cannot be in it.

**My question:**

> How do I programmatically achieve the above as if one can put `aligned` inside `aligned`?

Considering this is a rare situation, there's nothing too wrong about manual alignment, and asking for a robust construct is probably kind of silly. However, I think this staircase structure is kind of fun, so I have got to ask.

#### MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{ \partial \mathbb{E}[ X ] }{ \partial j} \approx  \frac1{A_h} \frac{\partial}{\partial j} \left( \frac23 A_K \right)
    &= \frac1{A_h} \frac23 S_{ \underline{ \theta}_K }    \\
& \begin{aligned}[t]
    &\approx \frac1{A_h} \frac23 S_{ \underline{ \theta}_h }\approx \frac1{A_h} \frac23 \underline{ \hat{ \theta} }_h \\
&\hspace{51pt} \approx \left( \frac23 \underline{ \hat{ \theta} }_h \right)^{-1} \frac23 \underline{ \hat{ \theta} }_h = 1
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is possible to do, but first you need to show, what you try so far. it is not fun rewrite your equation ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nest `aligned` in `aligned`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs,bm}

\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\bm{#1}} % change to \underline{#1} if you prefer
\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\pder{\mathbb{E}[\mathscr{X}]}{j}
=\frac{1}{A_h}\pder{}{j}\biggl(\frac{2}{3}A_K\biggr)
&=\frac{1}{A_h}\frac{2}{3}S_{\vect{\theta}_K}
\\
&\approx\begin{aligned}[t]
\frac{1}{A_h}\frac{2}{3}S_{\vect{\theta}_h}
&\approx\frac{1}{A_h}\frac{2}{3}\hat{\vect{\theta}}_h \\
&\approx\biggl(\frac{2}{3}\hat{\vect{\theta}}_h\biggr)^{\!-1}
\frac{2}{3}\hat{\vect{\theta}}_h=1
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just to show where this is important, I'll make the first line artificially longer; with a single `alignat` you wouldn't get this alignment.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this layout with `alignat`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\pderiv}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
  \pderiv{E[X]}{j} \approx 
    \frac{1}{A_h} \pderiv{}{j} \biggl( \frac{2}{3} A_K \biggr) 
    &= \frac{1}{A_h} \frac{2}{3} S_{\underline{\theta}_K} \\
    &\approx \frac{1}{A_h} \frac{2}{3} S_{\underline{\theta}_K}
      &&\approx \frac{1}{A_h} \frac{2}{3} \underline{\hat{\theta}}_h \\
    & &&\approx \biggl( \frac{2}{3} \underline{\hat{\theta}}_h \biggr)^{-1}
          \frac{2}{3} \underline{\hat{\theta}}_h = 1
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

A similar layout with `align` and `\hphantom` is also possible:

```
\begin{align}
  \pderiv{E[X]}{j} \approx 
    \frac{1}{A_h} \pderiv{}{j} \biggl( \frac{2}{3} A_K \biggr) 
    &= \frac{1}{A_h} \frac{2}{3} S_{\underline{\theta}_K} \\
    &\approx \frac{1}{A_h} \frac{2}{3} S_{\underline{\theta}_K}
      \approx \frac{1}{A_h} \frac{2}{3} \underline{\hat{\theta}}_h \\
    & \hphantom{{}\approx \frac{1}{A_h} \frac{2}{3} S_{\underline{\theta}_K}} 
      \approx \biggl( \frac{2}{3} \underline{\hat{\theta}}_h \biggr)^{-1}
          \frac{2}{3} \underline{\hat{\theta}}_h = 1
\end{align}
```

Overlap for elements that could affect the alignment may be corrected for with the use of `\mathrlap` (from [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)). Here's an example:

[image]

```
\usepackage{mathtools}

% ...

\begin{alignat}{2}
  \pderiv{E[X]}{j} \approx 
    \frac{1}{A_h} \pderiv{}{j} \biggl( \frac{2}{3} A_K \biggr) 
    &= \frac{1}{A_h} \frac{2}{3} S_{\underline{\theta}_K} 
      \mathrlap{{}+ xyzklmno} \\
    &\approx \frac{1}{A_h} \frac{2}{3} S_{\underline{\theta}_K}
      &&\approx \frac{1}{A_h} \frac{2}{3} \underline{\hat{\theta}}_h \\
    & &&\approx \biggl( \frac{2}{3} \underline{\hat{\theta}}_h \biggr)^{-1}
          \frac{2}{3} \underline{\hat{\theta}}_h = 1
\end{alignat}
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually mentioned `hphantom` in my question statement but I forgot to say that I really don't like phatoms cuz it makes the code very unreadable.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'm like "DUH---". I actually use `alignat` sometimes, but apparently not quite enough.

Answer (score 3):

Why nested environments if you can obtain the desired result with a simple `array`?

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
    \begin{array}{rcl}
xxxx = yyyyy & = zzzz   &           \\
             & = uuuu   & = vvvv    \\
             &          & = wwww
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Considering your MWE, the solution using `array` is:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
    \begin{array}{rcl}
\frac{\partial E[X]}{j} 
    \approx \frac{1}{A_h} \frac{\partial}{\partial j} \left\bgroup \frac{2}{3} A_K \right\rgroup
    & = \frac{1}{A_h} \frac{2}{3} S_{\underline{\theta}_K} 
        &                                                                   \\
    & \approx \frac{1}{A_h} \frac{2}{3} S_{\underline{\theta}_h}
        & \approx \frac{1}{A_h} \frac{2}{3} \underline{\hat{\theta}}_h      \\
    &   & \approx \left(\frac{2}{3} \underline{\hat{\theta}}_h \right)^{-1}
            \frac{2}{3} \underline{\hat{\theta}}_h = 1
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Giving:

[image]

Note: your way to write fractions is dangerous. Don't do this. `\frac{1}{2}` require a bit more work, but it is (far) more clear...

Comment: Always a good idea to go back to the basics! Thanks.

Comment: Why is it `\frac12` dangerous? At worst you'll get an error or incorrect output, which you can just look at and fix when proofreading. :-)

Comment: not follow original (deliberately defined)  `latex` syntax is not good idea. i only warn you. however, you can write as you wish.

Comment: Yes but what is the warning? What is the danger? Why is it not a good idea? Just aesthetics?

Comment: i'm not sure why, but in your first example, the first equal sign on the second line (before *uuuu*) isn't directly under the intended equal sign on the first line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, indeed. i don't know, what is cause for this. it seems that the second example doesn't suffer for this misalignment.